# What is wrong in this php code? Retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong in this code? Here I am trying to show the data fetched from a mySQL database when someone clicks on the "Show" button (Which is a submit button).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "rms", "sarangi", "rms");
    if($mysqli === false){
        die("Connection Error.");
    }
    else{
        echo'<table border="1"><tr><th> Name </th><th> Username </th></tr>';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        if($result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($data = $result->fetch_array()){
                    echo'<tr><td>' . $data['firstname'] . " " .     $data['lastname'] . '</td><td>' . $data['username'] . '</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo'</table>';
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
else{
?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Show" />
</form>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Before we can tell you what is wrong, you have to tell us what you expect to happen and what is actually happening. Why do you suspect that something is wrong? Are you getting any errors? Please add some additional information to your post so that we can understand the context in which the problem exists.

Comment: It looks reasonable to me, assuming the `users` table has columns `firstname`, `lastname`, and `username`.

Comment: There's no need to check `num_rows`. If there aren't any rows, the `while` loop will just terminate immediately.

Comment: Your IF block is never executed because isset($_POST['submit']) will always return false, you have to give "name" to your input tag

Comment: You must provide more information, SO is not a debuggin service I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You have to name your input field

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Show" />
```

should be

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Show" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Show" />
</form>
```

I have changed form action to "" since its going to submit to the same page. or you can leave it as index.php if this page is index.php. You need to put the name attribute of input submit as submit